# If $X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$ what is $\text{Var}{(X/Y)}$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If $X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$ what is

$$\text{Var}{(X/Y)}$$

Such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: It's not defined as even $E(X/Y)$ doesn't exists (unless $Y$ is degenerate and not $0$).

Comment: @A.S. What about this case? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544802/show-that-if-x-sim-n0-1-and-y-sim-n0-1-then-fracxy-sim-mathcal
Y is not degenerate here?

Comment: Try to compute mean of the Cauchy.

Comment: @A.S. Ah.. thank you..

Comment: @A.S. We have that if $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ are independent, then $X/Y\sim\textrm{Cauchy}(0,1)$. It seems that if the means are not equal to zero, this might not be the case anymore. Does this also hold for arbitrary parameters $\mu_X, \sigma_X^2,\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y^2$?

Comment: @Cm7 $E(X/Y)=E(X)E(Y^{-1})$ and $E(Y^{-1})$ diverges as density of $Y$ at $0$ is positive.